# CSS hover box position issue

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Currently I'm using following CSS to show a hover box:

```
.box {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 12px Arial, Sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
}
```

the javascript function:

```
function showBox(i,j){
                if(i==1){
                    document.getElementById("box"+j).style.display='block';
                } else if(i==2) {
                    document.getElementById("box"+j).style.display='none';
                }
            }
```

the html code:

```
<div style="height:175px;overflow:auto;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,1);" onmouseout="showBox(2,1);" id="hover1">Hover Me 1</p>
                                    <div id="box1" class="box">I'm hover box 1.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,2);" onmouseout="showBox(2,2);" id="hover2">Hover Me 2</p>
                                    <div id="box2" class="box">I'm hover box 2.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,3);" onmouseout="showBox(2,3);" id="hover3">Hover Me 3</p>
                                    <div id="box3" class="box">I'm hover box 3.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,4);" onmouseout="showBox(2,4);" id="hover4">Hover Me 4 </p>
                                    <div id="box4" class="box">I'm hover box 4.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,5);" onmouseout="showBox(2,5);" id="hover5">Hover Me 5</p>
                                    <div id="box5" class="box">I'm hover box 5.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,6);" onmouseout="showBox(2,6);" id="hover6">Hover Me 6</p>
                                    <div id="box6" class="box">I'm hover box 6.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p onmouseover="showBox(1,7);" onmouseout="showBox(2,7);" id="hover7">Hover Me 7</p>
                                    <div id="box7" class="box">I'm hover box 7.</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

If you run this you will find that a hover box is appeared when you hover on any "Hover ME X" text. This works fine until you have not scrolled down in div. When you scrolled down in div the hover box is showing in wrong position. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: First step: use divs for layout. Second step: Come back when you fixed step One.

Comment: He is comfortable with table so he is using it wats wrong with it?

Comment: Also your code is incomplete and doesn't fully demonstrate the problem, I can't reproduce it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
position: absolute;
```

And you use negative and positive margins, you will be able to place the div wherever you  want (eliminating the need for using anything other than position: absolute), the margins will just be relative to wherever the div is placed in the code.
Another bug with the coding is that the div shows up (at least in my browser {chrome}) before you even hover above the text that activates it. A very quick fix for this, to ensure the proper functionality in all (or most) browsers, is to add the following style to the CSS style "box":

```
display: none;
```

This will hide the DIV by default, in turn, stopping it from showing up on the page load. Then when you hover above the text the "display: block" in the JavaScript will overwrite it, so there will be no issues.

The final outcome of my "box" css style is:

```
padding: 3px; margin-left:-10px; margin-top:15px; color: #fff; font: normal 12px Arial, Sans-serif; position:absolute; display:none; padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px; border:#333333 1px solid; border-radius:3px; width:224px;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your positioning the box absolutely:

```
position: absolute;
```

Instead try positioning relative or fixed.

```
position:fixed;
```

Comment: Changing to fixed have same effect and relative works but where I'm using this hover box is big in height and I don't want it to take space when hovering.

Comment: You might need to get the position of the element your mouseovering and move somewhere relative to it. Or if your lazy, use DOM Window: http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html Check out example 7, I think it's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is that until u scroll the page the div will be positioned in the proper position, and when scroll down u have to keep in mind that ur page have extended from the default screen size, so when positioning the div you have to consider the facts **scroll top** and **scroll left**, then only you have the div positioned correctly. Try defining expressions within the css or manually write your own function to position the div.
Hope this helps you.